# How to allow players to give themselves a tag through /trigger

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Context:

I have a bunch of scheduled tellraw commands which give the players gameplay tips, which is useful for those who are new to our server's modpack.

Now that some players are accustomed to the modpack and don't need the tips, I want to give them the option to disable these tips through a simple /trigger command, which will give them a "DisableTips" tag. The scheduled tellraw commands for tips are written like this:

```
/tellraw @a[tag=!DisableTips] (example gameplay tip here)
```

So in conclusion, if they have the DisableTips tag, they will be excluded from receiving tips.

How can I allow players to give themselves the DisableTips tag through a trigger command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger commands are fairly easy to use and set up, but here is a quick run through:

1. You need a `trigger` type objective that players can use, let's say you call it `DisableTips`.
2. For players to be able to run `/trigger` on an objective, you need to `/scoreboard ... enable` the objective for those players.
3. Check for changes in this scoreboard. There are multiple ways to do this, also depends on how you expect players to trigger this.

So, let's assume that you just want players to be able to run `/trigger DisableTips` to add the corresponding tag. That means in concrete terms you need the following commands.

Setup:

```
scoreboard objectives add DisableTips trigger
```

Repeating-chain of commandblocks (or in a function), all always active and unconditional

```
scoreboard players enable @a DisableTips

tag @a[scores={DisableTips=1..}] add DisableTips
tellraw @a[scores={DisableTips=1..}] ["Tips have been disabled"]
scoreboard players reset @a[scores={DisableTips=1..}]
```

With a few changes you can make this a toggle to turn it back on at will, or change it to use the value in the scoreboard objective instead of adding another tag on top of the scoreboard objective.

Comment: How can I turn this into a toggleable command?

Comment: @D.Tunus which part you want toggleable? The commandblocks? Just set the first repeating commandblock to needs redstone and put a lever on it. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a lobby of some kind you could use two command blocks: one that enables tips for `@p`, one that disables it. If you don't like that solution, you could write up a mod that registers a custom command that toggles the tag on the player that runs it. (Contact me via a GitHub issue [in this repo](https://github.com/AdamRaichu/AdamRaichu) if you decide you want a mod; I'd be happy to do that for you. Just let me know which modloader you are using.)

```
# Command to enable tips for the nearest player.
tag @p add DisableTips

# Command to disable tips for the nearest player.
tag @p remove DisableTips
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the question carefully enough before answering. Sorry for the unhelpful answer.